# Annual Side by side bar plot with species on the x and count on y

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data set as shown below. I would like to have species on the x-axis and count on the y axis. For each species I would like to have a separate bar for year. So some species were counted for all four years and would ideally like to see 4 different color bars above that species label on the x-axis.

My attempt:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = species_capture, y = count, fill = year)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2")
```

Data:

```
data <-
  structure(
    list(
      year = c(
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2020,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2021,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2022,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023,
        2023
      ),
      species_capture = c(
        "aplastodiscus_albosignatus",
        "aplastodiscus_arildae",
        "boana_bandeirantes",
        "boana_faber",
        "bokermannohyla_circumdata",
        "bokermannohyla_hylax",
        "brachycephalus_pitanga",
        "chiasmocleis_cf._atlantica",
        "controle",
        "dendrophryniscus_haddadi",
        "dendropsophus_microps",
        "dendropsophus_minutus",
        "dendropsophus_seniculus",
        "fritziana_ohausi",
        "haddadus_binotatus",
        "hylodes_asper",
        "hylodes_phyllodes",
        "ischnocnema_henselii",
        "ischnocnema_parva",
        "leptodactylus_latrans",
        "ololygon_aff_brieni",
        "ololygon_perpusilla",
        "phrynomedusa_dryade",
        "physalaemus_olfersii",
        "rhinella_icterica",
        "scinax_flavoguttatus",
        "scinax_hayii",
        "vitreorana_uranoscopa",
        "?",
        "adenomera_marmorata",
        "aplastodiscus_albosignatus",
        "aplastodiscus_arildae",
        "aplastodiscus_leucopygius",
        "boana_bandeirantes",
        "boana_faber",
        "boana_pardalis",
        "bokermannohyla_circumdata",
        "bokermannohyla_hylax",
        "brachycephalus_pitanga",
        "controle",
        "cycloramphus_sp.",
        "dendrophryniscus_haddadi",
        "dendropsophus_microps",
        "dendropsophus_minutus",
        "dendropsophus_seniculus",
        "fritziana_fissilis",
        "fritziana_ohausi",
        "haddadus_binotatus",
        "hylodes_asper",
        "hylodes_phyllodes",
        "ischnocnema_henselii",
        "ischnocnema_nigriventris",
        "ischnocnema_parva",
        "leptodactylus_latrans",
        "ololygon_aff_brieni",
        "ololygon_perpusilla",
        "phrynomedusa_dryade",
        "physalaemus_cuvieri",
        "physalaemus_olfersii",
        "proceratophrys_appendiculata",
        "proceratophrys_boiei",
        "rhinella_icterica",
        "rhinella_ornata",
        "scinax_flavoguttatus",
        "scinax_hayii",
        "trachycephalus_imitatrix",
        "vitreorana_uranoscopa",
        "hylodes_phyllodes",
        "ischnocnema_henselii",
        "aplastodiscus_leucopygius",
        "boana_bandeirantes",
        "boana_faber",
        "boana_pardalis",
        "bokermannohyla_circumdata",
        "bokermannohyla_hylax",
        "brachycephalus_pitanga",
        "controle",
        "dendrophryniscus_haddadi",
        "dendropsophus_microps",
        "dendropsophus_minutus",
        "fritziana_fissilis",
        "haddadus_binotatus",
        "hylodes_asper",
        "hylodes_phyllodes",
        "ischnocnema_henselii",
        "ischnocnema_parva",
        "leptodactylus_latrans",
        "ololygon_aff_brieni",
        "ololygon_aff_littoralis",
        "ololygon_perpusilla",
        "phrynomedusa_dryade",
        "physalaemus_olfersii",
        "proceratophrys_appendiculata",
        "proceratophrys_boiei",
        "rhinella_icterica",
        "rhinella_ornata",
        "scinax_flavoguttatus",
        "scinax_hayii",
        "vitreorana_uranoscopa",
        "aplastodiscus_arildae",
        "aplastodiscus_leucopygius",
        "boana_bandeirante",
        "boana_bischoffi",
        "boana_faber",
        "bokermannohyla_circumdata",
        "bokermannohyla_hylax",
        "brachycephalus_nodoterga",
        "brachycephalus_sp",
        "control",
        "dendrophryniscus_haddadi",
        "dendropsophus_minutus",
        "haddadus_binotatus",
        "hylodes_phyllodes",
        "ischnocnema_henselii",
        "ischnocnema_parva",
        "ischnocnema_randorum",
        "ischnocnema_sp",
        "leptodactylus_marmoratus",
        "ololygon_cf_litoralis",
        "ololygon_perpusilla",
        "paratelmatobius_cardosoi",
        "paratelmatobius_poecilogaster",
        "physalaemus_cuvieri",
        "physalaemus_sp",
        "rhinella_icterica",
        "rhinella_ornata",
        "scinax_hayii",
        "vitreorana_uranoscopa"
      ),
      count = c(
        4,
        2,
        11,
        5,
        4,
        8,
        72,
        1,
        3,
        11,
        16,
        11,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        1,
        13,
        16,
        6,
        1,
        5,
        2,
        1,
        21,
        5,
        4,
        15,
        6,
        1,
        1,
        6,
        25,
        21,
        26,
        18,
        1,
        20,
        60,
        742,
        12,
        6,
        142,
        24,
        26,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        9,
        6,
        76,
        116,
        7,
        47,
        2,
        52,
        32,
        4,
        2,
        17,
        1,
        51,
        35,
        5,
        29,
        14,
        1,
        21,
        20,
        20,
        13,
        21,
        10,
        1,
        11,
        34,
        487,
        9,
        71,
        1,
        20,
        2,
        3,
        2,
        57,
        67,
        20,
        4,
        52,
        6,
        26,
        2,
        11,
        1,
        9,
        5,
        2,
        51,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        3,
        10,
        15,
        7,
        9,
        21,
        2,
        1,
        3,
        12,
        27,
        1,
        16,
        16,
        41,
        1,
        3,
        17,
        1,
        2,
        2,
        2,
        1,
        5,
        1,
        7,
        1,
        2
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-128L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )
```

Comment: could simply use fill = factor(year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = species_capture, y = count, fill = factor(year))) +   
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +   
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.3))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a composite column and chart that:

```
data$species_capture_year = paste0(data$species_capture,"-",data$year)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = species_capture_year, y = count, fill = factor(year))) +
   geom_col(position = "dodge2")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

another would be to facet the plot:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = year, y = count, fill = factor(year))) +
   geom_col(position = "dodge2")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
   facet_wrap(vars(species_capture))
```

given the wide variability in your y-axis counts you could also modify the above to allow adaptive scaling of the y-axis:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = year, y = count, fill = factor(year))) +
   geom_col(position = "dodge2")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
   facet_wrap(vars(species_capture), scales = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting year as a factor, rather than continuous. (I rotated x-axis labels for readability, as well.)

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = species_capture, y = count, fill = as.factor(year))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```